# What are some good ways of optimizing images for the web? (Figma wireframe to code)

Tags: html, css

I'm building my own portfolio from scratch. There are a lot of high-quality images that I want to include but I don't know how to do it without slowing down the site or sacrificing too much image resolution.

I created my wireframes in Figma but when I exported the images, the quality got reduced significantly. If I export them 2x or 3x, the resolution gets better but then it's a tradeoff with speed. I'm pretty new to front-end, trying to code my own website as a way to learn to code so please help. My questions are:

1. What is a good practice to optimize images for the web?
2. How to know if your image is too big? What is the typical size of an optimized image?
3. What are some tips/tricks/resources that I can further look into?
   Thanks a bunch

Comment: Anecdotal - For photos I go with 1920px wide with 60% quality jpegs when saving from photoshop

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into lazy loading images, it loads in a lower quality version at the start and then uses JavaScript to show the full quality when the user reaches that point of your website.

Here is some reference from google going into more depth :
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/lazy-loading-guidance/images-and-video/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do with high quality images:

**Lazy Loading**: using JavaScript the images loads once the user scrolls into view to that part of your website. The benefit is it doesn't load resources that aren't needed, meaning quicker load times and more efficient page loading.

More about it here: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/lazy-loading-guidance/images-and-video/

**Progressive Loading (like how Medium does it):**
You load in a really low-quality image and then progressively load in higher versions of that image over time. This has the benefit of showing the user something will show here eventually.

More about it here:
https://jmperezperez.com/medium-image-progressive-loading-placeholder/

**Alternatively file formats:**
Consider using alternatively file formats like WebP. Although be careful with browser support, but you can set a fallback of JPEG or PNG

More about it here:
https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/

**Other things to note:**
Good/standard practice is make sure to compress your images. If it is on the web then 72 DPI resolution (not like 300 for print), RGB colour format and make sure to use the right file format such as PNG for icons or transparent backgrounds and JPEG for more detailed pictures. Where possible use SVG over PNG and JPEG for vector based graphics.

In terms of sizing a common mistake is people put in a 4000 x 4000 size image into say a 600 x 600 image frame so make sure your images aren't overly sized for that space.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Google recommends that the photo should be about 200kb so I know that this is really not enough :) I am also involved in photography. I have have a website prepared so that it is indexed and has even 80 pictures per page and the site is very fast. At https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ it's 100/100 and it's indexed by google;) I use several sizes of the same image depending on the screen width as well.

I'm using IntersectionObserver with which I only load those pictures that are visible on the screen for this page to work very fast.

Below is an example of how one photo looks for different screen widths.

```
<picture>
  <source data-srcset="./images/lwow/576/IMG_0114.jpg" media="(max-width: 576px)"> 
  <source data-srcset="./images/lwow/768/IMG_0114.jpg" media="(max-width: 768px)"> 
  <source data-srcset="./images/lwow/992/IMG_0114.jpg" media="(max-width: 992px)"> 
  <source data-srcset="./images/lwow/1200/IMG_0114.jpg" media="(max-width: 1200px)"> 
  <img data-src="./images/lwow/1200/IMG_0114.jpg">
  <noscript><img src="./images/lwow/1200/IMG_0114.jpg"></noscript>
</picture>
```

Here is the link to the whole code https://github.com/tomik23/photoBlog

PS. A very important photo exported from photoshop is optimized using https://tinyjpg.com/
Unfortunately, photoshop is not suitable for photo optimization.
For my needs, I prepared a biblical to generate several photos at once in different resolutions and format and is called sharp-images on my githab